# Evaluate NA_integer_ from a string

Tags: r, integer, na

How do I read a value (from a file) like `"NA_integer"` and have R interpret it as if `NA_integer` was typed explicitly.

Here are two of my failed attempts:

```
q <- "NA_integer_"
get(q)        # Returns "Error in get(q) : object 'NA_integer_' not found"
eval(q)       # Returns the character value
```

This is the closest I could get.  But I don't like it because it sacrifices a lot of generalizability.

```
f <- "as.integer"
v <- NA
do.call(f, list(v))
```

**edit**: added the trailing underscore

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to `?NA`

> NA is a logical constant of length 1 which contains a missing value
>   indicator. NA can be coerced to any other vector type except raw.
>   There are also constants NA_integer_, NA_real_, NA_complex_ and
>   NA_character_ of the other atomic vector types which support missing
>   values: all of these are reserved words in the R language.

So we need

```
q <- "NA_integer_"
```

and then use

```
eval(parse(text=q))
#[1] NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe when reading in the file set the `na.strings` argument, see below example:

```
# dummy file
write.csv(data.frame(myCol = c(1:2, "NA", "NA_integer_")),
          "myFile.csv")


# this reads only NA as NA, and column is class of Factor, not what we want...
df1 <- read.csv("myFile.csv")
is.na(df1$myCol)
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
str(df1)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
#   $ X    : int  1 2 3 4
#   $ myCol: Factor w/ 3 levels "1","2","NA_integer_": 1 2 NA 3


# once we set na.strings, it reads both NAs and NA_integer_ as NAs and column is class of int.
df1 <- read.csv("myFile.csv", na.strings = c("NA", "NA_integer_"))
is.na(df1$myCol)
# [1] FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
str(df1)
# 'data.frame': 4 obs. of  2 variables:
#   $ X    : int  1 2 3 4
#   $ myCol: int  1 2 NA NA
```